# Javascript onclick listener

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem which is driving me crazy. 
I'm iterating through a set of  elements. Let's say the set has size N. In every iteration I write `node.onclick = function() { handleClick(idx); };` where node is the  element and idx is a global variable which I increment in every iteration. 
My goal is to listen for the N elements in such a way that when element i (i belongs to [0, N-1]) is clicked, that handleClick(idx) is invoked with argument idx=i. 
However, debugging shows up that, no matter which of the elements was clicked, within handleClick(idx), idx will be always equal to N-1 (the last value). I also tried the same with idx as a local variable.
I tried to create a global array node[] which is pushing a new element in every iteration...

How can I set the "onclick" listener to N different  elements such as the handler function be the same but the argument of that function be different?
How to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Of course it shows the last number, you're using *idx is a global variable*. Just a little time debugging and you could fiz that by yourfelf ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is described by DontVoteMeDown, a solution is to create a anoymous function like this:

```
node.onclick = (function(idx) {
    return function() { handleClick(idx); };
})(idx);
```

What this does is directly call the anoymous function so the id is copied into a new variable which remeains inside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for(var i = 0; i<set.length; i++){
    set[i].onclick = function(){
        handleClick(i);
    }
}
```